# Center HTML Div Using CSS

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

How would I horizontally center the following div with the following css. I've tried various methods but nothing seems to work. What can I do to fix this problem? Thank you very much.

**CSS:**

```css
    @import "compass/css3";

    .flexsearch--wrapper 
    {
     max-width: 90%;
     overflow: hidden;
     background: transparent;
    }
     
    .flexsearch--form {
     overflow: hidden;
     position: relative;
    }
     
    .flexsearch--input-wrapper {
     padding: 0 66px 0 0; /* Right padding for submit button width */
     overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .flexsearch--input {
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    /***********************
     * Configurable Styles *
     ***********************/
    .flexsearch {
      padding: 0 25px 0 200px; /* Padding for other horizontal elements */
    }
    
    .flexsearch--input {
      -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
     box-sizing: content-box;
      height: 60px;
      padding: 0 46px 0 10px;
     border-color: #333;
      border-radius: 35px; /* (height/2) + border-width */
      border-style: solid;
     border-width: 5px;
      margin-top: 15px;
      color: #333;
      font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
     font-size: 26px;
     -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
    }
     
    .flexsearch--submit {
      position: absolute;
     right: 0;
     top: 0;
     display: block;
     width: 60px;
     height: 60px;
      padding: 0;
      border: none;
     margin-top: 20px; /* margin-top + border-width */
      margin-right: 5px; /* border-width */
     background: transparent;
      color: #333;
      font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
      font-size: 40px;
      line-height: 60px;
    }
    
    .flexsearch--input:focus {
      outline: none;
      border-color: #333;
    }
    
    .flexsearch--input:focus.flexsearch--submit {
      color: #333; 
    }
    
    .flexsearch--submit:hover {
      color: #333;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
     color: #333;  
    }
    
    input:-moz-placeholder {
      color: #333
    }
```

```html
    <div class="flexsearch">
      <div class="flexsearch--wrapper">
       <form class="flexsearch--form" action="#" method="post">
        <div class="flexsearch--input-wrapper">
         <input class="flexsearch--input" type="search" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <input class="flexsearch--submit" type="submit" value="&#10140;"/>
       </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using `margin:0 auto;`? *"I've tried various methods but nothing seems to work"* What methods have you tried? It would be relevant to include those to your question as it might save people suggesting the same or might be able to tell you why that/those methods didn't work and offer you a solution to using it.

Comment: Fairly sure that didn't work but will try. Which div should I add margin: 0 auto; to?

Comment: **Itay Ganor**'s answer below shows you. :p Beat me to it.

Comment: What does the 200px padding he added mean?

Comment: All is explained in the comments below **Itay Ganor**' answer.

Comment: Based on your comment in the CSS, `/* Padding for other horizontal elements */`, could you show, with a drawing, what that means, as the now given answer is most like not going to solve it when you add that stuff. I think you will need a couple of columns to accomplish this in the end

Answer (score 3):

add `margin: auto;` to `.flexsearch--wrapper`.
Then, remove the `padding` from `.flexsearch` and add `max-width: 350px; margin: auto;`. That way the input looks good and won't break when using small width viewport.

Thanks @NewToJS.

```css
.flexsearch--wrapper 
{
    max-width: 90%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: transparent;
    margin: auto;
}

.flexsearch--form {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.flexsearch--input-wrapper {
    padding: 0 66px 0 0; /* Right padding for submit button width */
    overflow: hidden;
}

.flexsearch--input {
  width: 100%;
}

/***********************
 * Configurable Styles *
 ***********************/
.flexsearch {
  /* padding: 0 200px 0 200px; Padding for other horizontal elements */
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 350px;
}

.flexsearch--input {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    height: 60px;
  padding: 0 46px 0 10px;
    border-color: #333;
  border-radius: 35px; /* (height/2) + border-width */
  border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  color: #333;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
    font-size: 26px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}

.flexsearch--submit {
  position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
    margin-top: 20px; /* margin-top + border-width */
  margin-right: 5px; /* border-width */
    background: transparent;
  color: #333;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.flexsearch--input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #333;
}

.flexsearch--input:focus.flexsearch--submit {
    color: #333; 
}

.flexsearch--submit:hover {
  color: #333;
  cursor: pointer;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #333;  
}

input:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #333
}
```

```html
<div class="flexsearch">
        <div class="flexsearch--wrapper">
            <form class="flexsearch--form" action="#" method="post">
                <div class="flexsearch--input-wrapper">
                    <input class="flexsearch--input" type="search" placeholder="Search">
                </div>
                <input class="flexsearch--submit" type="submit" value="&#10140;"/>
            </form>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does the edited padding really do. I don't understand what the 200px even means...

Comment: The padding, as its name, adds padding between the `.flexsearch` border (which is the document's width) and its contents. You can read more about CSS shorthand syntax on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp). In our case, you want to have the div centered, so you need to have the same padding for both left and right. That's why you need to write `padding: 0 200px;` or `padding: 0 200px 0 200px;` => 0 padding from top, 200px padding from left, 0 padding from bottom, and 200px padding from right. Got it? :)

Comment: @MikeyMikey you don't need that padding for `.flexsearch` you can remove that and add `max-width:350px;` and `margin:0 auto;` Obviously you can set your own max-width. Example https://jsfiddle.net/t2gwwn55/

Comment: Of course, same effects. You can use whatever fits your needs or your way of thinking ;-)

Comment: @ItayGanor Not the same if the OP wants the input to keep the same size... using `padding` is just keeping 200px spacing at each side rather than just positioning the element. It does put it in the middle though. Just explaining the difference of your `padding` method to `max-width` & `margin` Change the window size of this, you will see the input display will fail if you resize (smaller) due to the padding https://jsfiddle.net/syefg36t/

Comment: Maybe this screenshot will help you understand what I mean https://i.imgur.com/QNEz1Gx.png

Comment: @ItayGanor Nothing wrong with your answer, I'm just explaining the reason for the padding but also pointing out a possible issue the OP might find so offering the other method. Still +1 because this is still a good solution :)